how to make isalnum() ignore \n
im doing a school exercise and im meant to write a small code where there is a txt file of "passwords"
and i need the program to check if the passwords are ok (so only alphabets no weird symbols)
but when i use "isalnum()" command, it reads the passwords all as "5345m345a34l\n" not as " 5345m345a34l"
this is how ive written the code as of now. the split command ive just now added through ryan's post
s = open("passwords.txt","w")
passwords = ("5345m345a34l\nno2no123non4\nnoq234n5ioqw#%\n%#""SGMSGSER\ndoghdp5234\nsg,dermoepm\n43453-frgsd\nhsth()))\nbmepm35wae\nvmopaem2234+0+\ngsdm12313")
s.write(passwords)
s.close

s = open("passwords.txt", "r")
read_row = 0
read_row = (s.readlines())

password_list = passwords.split("\n") #added with the help of ryan's comment
for passwords in password_list:
    if passwords.isalnum() == True:
        print(passwords, "correct password",end="\n")
    else:
        print(passwords, "contains incorrect markings",end="\n")
    
s.close()


Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow! Can you share the code you have so far for removing the newlines? You should be able to do passwords.replace('\n', '') or something similar.

@David hey i tried to use this
res = []
for sub in test_list:
res.append(re.sub('\n', '', sub))
code piece but i couldnt make use of it, also i cant format comments well so it might be hard to read.

That looks like it should work. Can you edit your post with a minimal reproducible example to help us help you?

Strip the trailing \n before you pass it to isalnum, since you already "know" it is not part of the password you are trying to validate. (The rstrip or strip methods are slightly simpler than replace or sub.) Please include how you define test_list in your question (not in a comment) as well, so that your question provides a [mcve] that we can replicate and diagnose.

Hey i just updated the post. it takes some time as i use a different language so i had to change all text to english. i got it working 95% of the way through ryan's help.

The 2 hardest problems in computer science are cache invalidation, naming, and off-by-one errors.  Which is to say that naming things is really, really important.  Instead of for passwords in ..., you probably ought to use for password in ....  password_list is a list of passwords, and each entry in that list is a single password.  Using a plural name for an individual entry is invited unnecessary confusion.

Try splitting the string into a list and checking each password in the list:
passwords = "5345m345a34l\nno2no123non4\nnoq234n5ioqw#%\n%#""SGMSGSER\ndoghdp5234\nsg,dermoepm\n43453-frgsd\nhsth()))\nbmepm35wae\nvmopaem2234+0+\ngsdm12313"

password_list = passwords.split("\n")
for password in password_list:
    if password.isalnum():
        print(password, "is a correct password",end="\n")
    else:
        print(password, "contains incorrect markings",end="\n")

Output:
5345m345a34l is a correct password
no2no123non4 is a correct password
noq234n5ioqw#% contains incorrect markings
%#SGMSGSER contains incorrect markings
doghdp5234 is a correct password
sg,dermoepm contains incorrect markings
43453-frgsd contains incorrect markings
hsth())) contains incorrect markings
bmepm35wae is a correct password
vmopaem2234+0+ contains incorrect markings
gsdm12313 is a correct password



Hey it works almost flawlessly except "%#""SGMSGSER" becomes "%#SGMSGSER"
and the program needs it to be 1:1 with the "example answer". im not really sure why its removing those little " symbols

@Bobby The syntax A = "string_1" "string_2" is the same as A = "string_1string_2" (it is exactly like there was a + in between. So either "%#" is part of the password, either you should remove it before checking for a valid password

@Lrx "%#""SGMSGSER" this is how the password is typed in the example answer. which is why it needs to be printed as "%#""SGMSGSER contains incorrect markings"

@Bobby in that case, you may want to use single quotes ' and not double quotes " to delimit your entire string so you should have password = '5345...dm12313' instead of password = "5345...dm12313"
